# How do I say "Is the sun out today" in Japanese?

Tags: translation

I've been searching everywhere for trying to find out how to say this phrase but specifically stuck on the "out" part.  Not sure on what the correct word choice should be used to say that but overall would greatly appreciate if someone could provide me the Japanese translation of the phrase.

Comment: How about: 今日{きょう}は晴{は}れですか。 --> The weather report often uses the term 晴{は}れ to mean "sunny".

Answer (score 3):

A natural and fairly common way to say it (***without sounding the least bit textbookish***)　would be:

> 「[今日]{きょう}、お[日様出]{ひさまで}てる？」 or
>
> 「今日**は**お日様出てる？」

This just happens accidentally but the phrase contains 「出る」 = "to come ***out***" if you want the "out" nuance in the Japanese.

Answer (score -1):

A more casual way could also be：
「今日は、太陽があるのか？」
though this could be considered a simple version and depending it could also be different.